# Infinite animation opacity not works for several elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

HTML:

```
<div id="my_div" class="all_divs"></div>
<div class="all_divs"></div>
<div class="all_divs"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.all_divs {
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
   background: #009;
   margin-top: 10px;
   opacity: 0;
}
```

JS/JQUERY:

```
function light() {
    $("#my_div").animate({opacity: 1}, 500, function() {
        shutdown();
    });
}

function shutdown() {
    $("#my_div").animate({opacity: 0}, 500, function() {
        light();
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    light();
});
```

When I try to animate only one div (`id="my_div"`), then this works properly, though when try to animate all of 3 elements, using `$(".all_divs")`, then animation crashes.

What is the reason for this?

Here is an example, when the selector is class `.all_divs` and animation crashes:

https://jsfiddle.net/oL65jax0/

And this is the expected result:

https://jsfiddle.net/oL65jax0/1/

Answer (score 0):

This happens because your "on animation end" callback calls `light()` and `shutdown()` for each element who has `all_divs` class (3 times every time). One way to solve this is to call `light()` and `shutdown()` only for last element.

```js
    function light() {
        $(".all_divs").animate({opacity: 1}, 500, function(i) {
          if (this === $(".all_divs").last().get(0))
            shutdown();
        });
    }
    function shutdown() {
        $(".all_divs").animate({opacity: 0}, 500, function() {
          if (this === $(".all_divs").last().get(0))
            light();
        });
    }


    $(document).ready(function() {
        light();
    });
```

```css
.all_divs {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #009;
  margin-top: 10px;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="my_div" class="all_divs"  ></div>
<div class="all_divs"  ></div>
<div class="all_divs" ></div>
```

Or you can save the last element somewhere so you don't have to recalculate it.

```js
function light() {
    $(".all_divs").animate({opacity: 1}, 500, function(i) {
      if (this === App.lastAnimatedElement)
        shutdown();
    });
}
function shutdown() {
    $(".all_divs").animate({opacity: 0}, 500, function() {
      if (this === App.lastAnimatedElement)
        light();
    });
}

var App = App || {};

$(document).ready(function() {
  App.lastAnimatedElement = $(".all_divs").last().get(0);
  light();
});
```

```css
.all_divs {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #009;
  margin-top: 10px;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="my_div" class="all_divs"  ></div>
<div class="all_divs"  ></div>
<div class="all_divs" ></div>
```